# tornado webserver unlimited subprocess forking

Tags: python, webserver, tornado

http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tcpserver.html#tornado.tcpserver.TCPServer.start

http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/httpserver.html

```
server = HTTPServer(app)
server.bind(8888)
server.start(0)  # Forks multiple sub-processes
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

When I set 0 in server.start(), tornado forks a maximum of X subprocesses (where X equals to the numbers of machine cores, in my case I have 4.)

To test it, I have two controllers, one controller (A) with a sleep(9999), and other quick controller (B) that simply returns "hello world"

When I make 3 concurrent request to the controller A, + one request to the B controller, all works fine, the "hello world" is returned.

but when I make 4 concurrent request to the controller A, + one request to the B controller,  the B request waits.

How can I no limit the number of forks?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an option to fork an unlimited number of subprocesses. The documentation states this:

> If num_processes is None or <= 0, we detect the number of cores
>   available on this machine and fork that number of child processes. If
>   num_processes is given and > 1, we fork that specific number of
>   sub-processes.

You could specify some high number if you wanted, but I think you'd find that at a certain point not too far above the number of cores on your system, it starts to hurt performance.

Tornado really isn't designed to be run in a way that requires forking many subprocesses. One of the major features of Tornado is asynchronous I/O, which will allow it to handle many more than `num_proccesses` number of concurrent connections. For example, if you were to replace your call to `sleep(9999)` in the A controller with a [non-blocking sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428231/how-does-long-polling-work-in-tornado/23876402#23876402), you'd be able to handle all connections to be B controller almost instantly.