# Python BadYieldError when yielding Future

Tags: python, tornado, future, yield, coroutine

I'm fairly new to programming using coroutines and I'm trying to build a database interface for a custom database for a Tornado web server using Python 2.7.10. However, I keep getting a `BadYieldError`. I feel that this is probably me not understanding how to fully use `tornado.gen.coroutine` with Python's `yield`. I think there may be something wrong with how I'm yielding a Future.

This is my code that keeps failing, where the `testGet` function at line 15 is a simulation of a foreign database access.

```
from tornado import gen
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        response = "Hello, world"
        response = yield db_interface("default", "user_query")
        self.write(str(response))


# meant to demonstrate
def testGet(query):
    gen.sleep(2)
    response = query
    return response


@gen.coroutine
def db_interface(db, key):
    print str(db)
    d = yield testGet(key)
    raise gen.Return(d)


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8889)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Output:

```
default
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception GET / (127.0.0.1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:8889', method='GET', uri='/', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-CA,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch', 'Host': '127.0.0.1:8889', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36', 'Dnt': '1', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cookie': 'ui-auth-127.0.0.1%3A8091=4f1301ef98f1b6fbd80ad059cd5aa2dc', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1415, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 870, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 876, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "test.py", line 12, in get
    response = yield db_interface("default", "user_query")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 870, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 876, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "test.py", line 26, in db_interface
    d = yield testGet(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 870, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 956, in handle_yield
    self.future = convert_yielded(yielded)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1026, in convert_yielded
    raise BadYieldError("yielded unknown object %r" % (yielded,))
BadYieldError: yielded unknown object 'user_query'
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET / (127.0.0.1) 2011.67ms
```

I've been trying to look for how to do this properly on [Tornado's official documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html) and on [this blog](https://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/), but I don't think I've been able to fully grasp what they're saying about how to use coroutines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either turn `testGet` into a coroutine like this so that it returns a future:

```
@gen.coroutine
def testGet(query):
    gen.sleep(2)
    raise gen.Return(query)
```

Or don't use `yield` on it: `d = testGet(key)`.

If you do either, the code works. You should be using `yield` on functions that return `Future`s.

Comment: Well `testGet` would be a database call, not a function, so I can't turn it into a coroutine. Is there any way I can yield from a function that yields? And if so, do you think it's a bad idea to?

Comment: I gave two options in the answer: convert to coroutine or drop the `yield` from  `d = yield testGet(key)`. Are you saying neither option work?

Comment: It isn't possible for me to turn `testGet` into a coroutine because it's not a function, but rather a representation of a foreign call that I'm using for demonstration purposes. The second one works, but why? Isn't it possible to `yield` a Future that represents a Future? If so, what was I doing wrong that your solution is better?

Comment: What I'm hearing you saying is that you cannot use the first option I gave (convert to coroutine), but you've still not said anything about the 2nd option (don't use `yield` on `testGet`'s return value).

Comment: I figured out the problem from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043076/tornado-coroutine).
"any place inside of a coroutine where you want to call `yield something()`, `something` must either also be a coroutine, or return a `Future`"